# Button to collape div with image and text allignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 3 I am using a button to collapse a div. I have an image and text and alternate between:

```
+ More
- Less
```

However, the image is misaligned to the text. Is there any way to align image and text in a content: button?

```css
button.btn.collapsed:before {
  content: url('plusImage.svg') " More";
}

button.btn:before {
  content: url('minusImage.svg') " Less";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMoreDetails"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I can use Bootstrap and everything is perfectly aligned.

```css
.text-toogle[aria-expanded=false] .text-expanded {
  display: none;
}

.text-toogle[aria-expanded=true] .text-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a class="btn btn-link text-toogle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMoreDetails" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="text-collapsed"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> More Details</span>
  <span class="text-expanded">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Less Details</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you separate the image and text into two different pseudo elements.

```css
button.btn::before, button.btn::after {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* using custom inline svg for demonstration purpose */
button.btn.collapsed::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 32 32'%3E%3Ctitle%3Eplus1%3C/title%3E%3Cpath d='M31 12h-11v-11c0-0.552-0.447-1-1-1h-6c-0.553 0-1 0.448-1 1v11h-11c-0.553 0-1 0.448-1 1v6c0 0.553 0.447 1 1 1h11v11c0 0.553 0.447 1 1 1h6c0.553 0 1-0.447 1-1v-11h11c0.553 0 1-0.447 1-1v-6c0-0.552-0.447-1-1-1z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}

button.btn.collapsed::after {
  content: " More"
}

button.btn::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 32 32'%3E%3Ctitle%3Eminus%3C/title%3E%3Cpath d='M1 12h30c0.553 0 1 0.448 1 1v6c0 0.553-0.447 1-1 1h-30c-0.552 0-1-0.447-1-1v-6c0-0.552 0.448-1 1-1z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

button.btn::after {
  content: " Less"
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMoreDetails"></button>
<button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMoreDetails"></button>
```